# Laravel / PHP and Jquery TABS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am sure most of you guys are aware of Jquery and it's easy to implement assets such as TABS.  I'm new to Laravel and am trying to implement Jquery TABS into it but i'm not have a lot of success.

I add the JS link in my master.blade file:-

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.tabs.custom.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Next up I'll add the div in my page.blade

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); }); </script>


<div class="someinfo">
                    <ul>
                    <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Some Detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">More Detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">All Detail</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div id="tabs-1">
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div id="tabs-2">
            <p></p>
          </div>
          <div id="tabs-3">
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>

                </div>
```

What's happening is the DIV's are all showing so it seems that the JS is not loading correctly.  Have I missed something out about implementing it to run?  Any help would be much appreciated as I can't find anything online about Jquery TABS with Laravel.

Comment: Sorry copied wrong JS link - : <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.tabs.custom.min.js') }}"></script>

Comment: Rather than add the JS link in the comment, edit your question and correct it there.

Comment: You should provide more details, most probable reason for not loading JS is invalid path to it. Check for errors in chrome dev tools or firebug.

Comment: so what does this have to do with `php` or `laravel`?

Comment: @w0rldart - I was wondering if there were any reasons Jquery TABS couldn't be implemented into Laravel as I'm unable to find any resources online between the 2.  But thanks for your valued input...

Comment: @Stjepano - Yea I thought as much although the checks are not showing up any errors. Puzzling me for over an hour now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you starting the tabs? They don't just start themselves, you need to have `$('#tabs').tabs();` in your javascript.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Scimonster Actually this is an answer, if the user didn't have that line in then it would have been the solution.

Comment: He also needs to include jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.css files.